# Manipulating paths in python

Tags: python, path-manipulation

I am writing a python script 2.5 in Windows whose `CurrentDir = C:\users\spring\projects\sw\demo\753\ver1.1\011\rev120\source` my file is `test.py`. From this path I would like to access  files in this path: `C:\users\spring\projects\sw\demo\753\ver1.1\011\rev120\Common\`

I tried using `os.path.join` but it does not work and I from the docs I understand why.
So what could be the best pythonic solution for this?

```
currentdir = os.getcwd()    
config_file_path =  os.path.join(currentdir,"\\..\\Common")
```

Comment: Post some code.  What's not working?

Comment: Code snippet would be helpful in tracking down the problem.

Comment: Why are you using an ancient python version?

Comment: @ThiefMaster My environment has a number of internal tools all based on python 2.5 so can't break it

Comment: Sounds like those tools should be tested with 2.6/2.7 (which should be easy since those versions do not introduce many changes which might break things) instead of keeping such an old version.

Comment: Save yourself some pain and just use `/` instead of \`\\\`. Should work fine on Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can be solved by using `os.path.join`, but you're not using it properly.

```
currentdir = os.getcwd()    
config_file_path =  os.path.join(currentdir,"\\..\\Common")
```

`"\\..\\Common"` is not a relative path, as it starts with `\`.

You need to join with `..\\Common`, which is a relative path.

Please note that `os.path.join` is not a simple string concatenation function, you don't need to insert the in-between antislashes.

So fixed code would be :

```
config_file_path =  os.path.join(currentdir,"..\\Common")
```

or, alternatively :

```
config_file_path =  os.path.join(currentdir, "..", "Common")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from os.path import dirname, join
join(dirname(dirname(__file__)), 'Common')
```

should work.

Comment: Importing everyhing into the global scope is pretty messy.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Just importing two functions hardly counts as "everything", and makes the line look less cryptic. Of course, you can write `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'Common')`

Comment: In a small script you are right, but in a module with a few hundred SLOC someone won't expect `join` to be from `os.path` but rather something more generic...

Comment: For my specific problem it may work but what about if I want to access files in C:\users\spring\projects\sw\demo\753\ver1.1 ? I will have to use dirname a number of times.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
joined = os.path.join('C:\\users\\spring\\projects\\sw\\demo\\753\\ver1.1\\011\\rev120\\source', '..\\Common\\')
# 'C:\\users\\spring\\projects\\sw\\demo\\753\\ver1.1\\011\\rev120\\source\\..\\Common\\'
canonical = os.path.realpath(joined)
# 'C:\\users\\spring\\projects\\sw\\demo\\753\\ver1.1\\011\\rev120\\Common'
```

Comment: I get my current dir using os.getcwd() which returns 'C:\users\spring\projects\sw\demo\753\ver1.1\011\rev120\source' and when I try to use join I only get C:\common which is not I want

Comment: @ThiefMaster The comment is a copy-paste from the Python interpreter. `join()` did not remove the `..`. I agree though that the path is usable as it is and the call to `realpath()` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @spring What's the output of `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '..\\Common')`?

Comment: I get `C:\users\spring\projects\sw\demo\753\ver1.1\011\rev120\source\..\Common\` when I substitute your path for os.getcwd(). I don't know why we are getting different results. I'm running Python 2.7 on Windows.